# get row count of last select query

Tags: postgresql

I am using a scheduled script which exports the (new) rows of the PostgreSQL database into a textfile. There are also several instances of this script running for several DBs:

```
COPY (SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY zzz) TO STDOUT >file.csv
```

In order to have a consistency check of the file.csv, I then run a query to get the number of lines which the `COPY` query had:

```
SELECT count(0) FROM ... GROUP BY zzz >linecount
```

In the bash script there is a check if both are equal, if that's the case the script proceeds, if not it stops and reports an error (which happens rarely, but it does - and i haven't figured out why yet)

The problem, the query result is rather large (takes around 5-10min) and it is basically running twice (although the `count(0)` takes shorter, but still 3-7min)

Is there a PostgreSQL function to get the number of rows the last query had? If that would be the case, I could cut down DB load quite a load and shorten the export time.

I have looked into `ROW_COUNT`, but it only seems to be valid for `UPDATE/INSERT` and not `SELECT`, I'd also like to avoid using functions for simplicity reasons.

I am open to alternative suggestions, eg first query into a temp table, then export from there (maybe `count(0)` is faster then)?

Debian 7 Wheezy, SSD, 32GB Ram, PostgreSQL 9.1

---

UPDATE @Craig Ringer

I agree that the consistency check is somewhat 'flawed' by design. I noticed once that the import-check had a problem i couldnt explain, I then ran the export again, and the file had different lines than the one before:

```
Rowcount DB/LinecountF:532395/532014

rowcount: SELECT count(0)... as described originally
linecount  = wc -l
```

They are running as cronjobs and I havent figured out why those lines were missing. Running the same script second time and everything was fine. It happens very rarely, but the logfile didnt say anything (or mail result from cron).

I didnt check the exit status of the PSQL tough (as I built in my own checks). I will do that.

Comment: The row counts could be different if you're not running both the copy and subsequent select in the same transaction with an isolation level of repeatable read or serializable, and something modifies the data in the table between the two commands.

Comment: Please note that `psql` is a client to PostgreSQL (or Postgres for short).

Comment: Are you sure nothing is writing to this table between your export and the second query?

Comment: Related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610449/get-the-count-of-rows-from-a-copy-command

Comment: @hbn Yes, nothing changes the data for the export between those two runs. For this database only new lines are added (and exported in batches of 500k IDs, so lets day >450000 <=500000). The content wont change ever, only new rows are added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension that tracks queries: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgstatstatements.html

You have to enable the extension and then change your postgresql.conf to load it in the server. But, after that there would be next to zero overhead to get how many rows were affected.

where you could do something like:

```
select rows from pg_stat_statements where query = 'the query'
```

where rows is the total rows affected (returned, inserted, updated, deleted.)

The only caveat is that rows is the *total affected rows* of every time the query executed so you have to check the total before and after the query executed. And, you would not want to have races executing the same script between the same database and user as that is how it groups the queries.

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing to forgo writing to STDOUT, you can get the number of rows that COPY exports with a PL/pgSQL function along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copyout(query text, output_path text) RETURNS integer AS $fn$
DECLARE
    result integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'COPY (' || query || $$) TO '$$ || output_path || $$'$$;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS result = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN result;
END
$fn$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Execute with something like this (note the path is on the *server* not the client):

```
> SELECT copyout('SELECT * FROM mytable', '/tmp/myfile.csv');
 copyout
---------
     981
(1 row)
```

However - just found out this was added in 9.3 (see [9.3 Release Notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3.html#AEN115708)). Sorry.

Comment: Huh. I was not aware that `COPY` set `ROW_COUNT` in PL/PgSQL. Learn something every day. I'd +10 if I could.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL does not report an affected-row count to the client application at command-completion for `SELECT` or `COPY`.

You must do this client-side. That's what `psql` does when it prints `(2 rows)` or whatever after a `SELECT` ... it just counts the rows as it reads them, and prints the count afterwards.

Note that you can't just count the number of *newlines* in the CSV, because a single CSV record can contain embedded newlines. You have to actually parse it to count the number of records.

Personally I think the whole concept of doing a "consistency check" is flawed. What do you expect to go wrong? What are you trying to check for? How are you counting the rows in the CSV to compare to the rowcount, and is *that* part currently correct given the above?

Here's roughly what you should be doing, with logic expressed as (ba)sh script:

```
outfile="my-file.csv"
tempfile=".my-tempfile.$$.csv"
if ! psql ...blahblahargs... -c '\copy (SELECT ...) TO '"$tempfile"' WITH (FORMAT CSV)
then
    rm -f "$tempfile"
    echo >&2 "COPY failed, see prior messages. Aborting."
    exit 1
else
    mv "$tempfile" "$outfile"
fi
```

What we're doing here is:

- `COPY`ing output to a temp file with a generated name;
- Once the `COPY` completes without error, renaming the file to the final location

If the `COPY` fails for any reason, the final file doesn't get created.

The temp file naming there is *very* simplistic; you should really use the `mktemp` utility command to generate a tempfile name, and if it's going into `/tmp` possibly create a tempdir. I omitted the details for simplicity and because I don't know exactly what you're doing here. I also left out the error `TRAP` that should be included in such a script, and handling of removal of abandoned tempfiles.